# Sort rows by a column, then sort the sorted rows by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
name | cat | time
a      1      0
b      2      1
c      3      2
d      1      3
e      2      4
```

I need to output something like this:

```
name | cat | time
d      1      3
a      1      0
e      2      4
b      2      1
c      3      2
```

I need to sort the rows by the column `cat` ascending, and then sort the sorted rows by `time` descending.

I tried with `ORBER BY cat ASC, time DESC`, but the results were just sorted by `cat`.

How can I solve this?

____ UPDATE_____

This is the query in PHP i give

```
$query = "SELECT fr_promo.id as promo_id,
                 fr_promo.name as promo_name,
                 fr_promo.description as promo_desc,
                 fr_promo.description2 as promo_desc2,
                 fr_promo.price as promo_price,
                 fr_promo.discount as promo_discount,
                 fr_promo.image as promo_image,
                 fr_promo.cat as promo_cat,
                 fr_shop.id as shop_id,
                 fr_shop.latitude as shop_latitude,
                 fr_shop.longitude as shop_longitude,
                 fr_shop.name as shop_name,
                 fr_shop.description as shop_description,
                 fr_shop.phone as shop_phone,
                 fr_shop.image as shop_image,
                 fr_cat.color as cat_color,
                 fr_shop.home as shop_home FROM fr_promo, fr_shop, fr_cat WHERE";

$query .= " fr_promo.status = ".$PROMO_STATUS['active']; // Only Active Promotion

// Relations Start
// $query .= " AND fr_promo.cat = $cat"; // Only relative to a cat
// Relations End

$query .= " AND fr_shop.status = ".$SHOP_STATUS['active']; // Shop Active
$query .= " AND fr_promo.id_shop = fr_shop.id"; // Relation
$query .= " AND fr_promo.cat = fr_cat.id"; // Relation
$query .= " ORDER BY fr_promo.cat ASC, fr_promo.date DESC LIMIT 50"; // Order
```

____ UPDATE HTML RESULTS ______

```
                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="3" data-timestamp="1433884559" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/6" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1430993987-243820-.webp.jpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="4" data-timestamp="1433885898" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/35" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1433509658-828387-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="4" data-timestamp="1433885627" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/45" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1433880871-507885-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="4" data-timestamp="1433880393" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/44" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1433880393-71521-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="4" data-timestamp="1433510267" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/36" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1433510267-565361-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="4" data-timestamp="1430998573" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/7" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1430998573-535602-niuzai.webp.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="4" data-timestamp="1430412118" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/3" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #009900;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1430412118-874494-tb1bv1ygfxxxxxgapxxxxxxxxxx_!!0-item_pic.jpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="7" data-timestamp="1431019740" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/8" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #926239;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1430998729-101842-tb1xryihpxxxxxyxxxxxxxxxxxx_!!0-item_pic.jpg_400x400.jpg_.webp.jpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="8" data-timestamp="1433362165" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/30" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #926239;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/189-1433362164-996579-dd.png" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="11" data-timestamp="1433965209" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/40" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/193-1433965209-755481-anm.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="11" data-timestamp="1433965129" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/41" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/193-1433965129-675286-2-120i11p056.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="11" data-timestamp="1433925696" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/46" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/196-1433925696-165442-.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="11" data-timestamp="1433869431" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/43" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/1981433773456667791imagejpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1433886056" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/11" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/4-1431676405-817577-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1433418988" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/32" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/5-1433418987-133297-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431776307" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/19" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/4-1431776307-129447-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431776225" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/18" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/5-1431776225-248962-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431776118" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/17" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/6-1431776118-174199-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431775678" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/16" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/6-1431775678-59578-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431775545" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/15" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/4-1431775545-383464-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431775374" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/14" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/5-1431775374-927887-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431677121" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/13" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/6-1431677121-21520-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="12" data-timestamp="1431676948" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/12" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #376bc7;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/5-1431676948-971379-image.jpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="19" data-timestamp="1433962164" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/38" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #e38503;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1433511139-897757-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="19" data-timestamp="1433962134" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/37" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #e38503;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1433511057-806543-image.jpg" /></a>



                <a data-cat="19" data-timestamp="1433962094" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/9" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #e38503;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/2-1431031328-244270-2013-02-0111.21.24.jpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="23" data-timestamp="1433594897" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/39" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #bf40ba;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/191-1433581684-870981-.jpg" /></a>



                    <!-- <div style="clear: both;"></div> -->


                <a data-cat="24" data-timestamp="1433764970" href="http://www.goubaoapp.com/p/42" target="_blank" ><img style="width: 72px; background: #bf40ba;" src="http://www.goubaoapp.com/upload/promo/icon/1971433764792561100imagejpg" /></a>
```

Comment: `ORBER BY cat ASC, time DESC` should solve it. Is this your actual data?

Comment: what type is the time column?

Comment: If it's all integers less than 10 it doesn't matter what the data type is; even if it's a character it'll still be sorted correctly... there's something the OP isn't telling us @Tony. The issue is unreproducible from the example given, therefore there needs to be a better example in order for anyone to be able to conclusively help.

Comment: "time" column is timestamp linux
"cat" column is integer

Comment: @Ben Well I'm going to take a wild guess here and suggest that what we haven't been told, is in fact it's a string with a number in it. Which is why I asked.

Comment: hmm both wrong. Good idea this asking stuff isn't it?

Comment: no, timestamp linux is integer... not a string... every columns of sorting are integer..

Comment: best give us some real data then.

Comment: @user3849948 try putting backticks on your column names for sorting.. since `time` is a key word that may be messing it up.. [**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67cd7/2)

Comment: @JohnRuddell If it were messing it up, he'd get a syntax error, not wrong results.

Comment: php code inserted, updated

Comment: @Barmar most likely but still worth a shot

Comment: @JohnRuddell `time` isn't even the real name of the column, it's `fr_promo.date`. He just used that in the example.

Comment: @Barmar as I just noticed from his update... can we see the actual data types on the columns?

Comment: Your `SELECT` list doesn't include `fr_promo.date`. How can you tell that it's not sorted by that column?

Comment: UPDATED with HTML results, you can see in data-cat and data-timestamp the columns value

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I confused group of subcategories with group of main categories.
Sorry for wasting your time, everythink was correct!